# No wireless detected, no drivers available

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 32bit on a Lenovo E520 with a Intel WiFi Link 1000 BGN device.

Though Windows7 can connect itself to WiFi as well as being able to see other WiFi networks, Ubuntu can not.

When I went to additional driver, no drivers are on the list.

How can I connect my laptop to wireless network and use drivers in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late for this, but if someone arrives here looking for this question, [here](http://exain.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/wireless-on-ubuntu-11-10-and-lenovo-thinkpad-e420/) is the answer. It worked for me in Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10.

Open a  terminal and type

```
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

You should be able to connect to the wireless till next reboot.

- Making the change permanent

Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` with your favorite text editor, ie `gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, and add this line at the end of the file

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Reboot and you’re done.

Please note: This applies to wireless card having **rtl8188ce** chipset. You can view that by typing `lspci` in a terminal and searching for the entries respective to *Network Controller*.

The problem should be solved for Ubuntu 12.04.